# Method argument validation of complex types

Tags: c#, validation, arguments, complextype

I'm a fan of argument validation in methods. Something like this is commonly seen in my code:

```
public void Foo(string someString)
{
    #region parameter validation
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someString))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("someString");
        // Let's ignore the .NET 4.6 nameof-feature for the sake of this question.
    #endregion

    // do things
}
```

Now let's say the method doesn't accept a string, but a complex object. Let's say I want the method to validate whether a property of this complex object is set. What would be the correct way to do this? Up until now I've done it like this:

```
public void Foo(Person person)
{
    #region parameter validation
    if(person == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("person");
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.Name))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("person.Name");
    #endregion

    // do things
}
```

Is there some best practice for this? Is `ArgumentNullException` the correct way to go? Is checking properties like this even recommended?

Comment: If it is really important to check, have you considered putting a static method within each class you are using to run these tests? Possibly make an interface that requires a method that runs tests on your properties?

Comment: `ArgumentNullException` assumes that the argument is `null`, not a white space string.

Comment: @kailanjian: no, because the validation isn't directly connected to the validity of the object; it's only to validate whether the object is in a state in which the method can work with it.

Comment: @AlexD: that's not helping. I'd appreciate if you could tell me the correct exception type or way of handling this scenario, not just saying that it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no offical correct way of doing this, so I will stick to my own way, which is

```
if(myComplexObject.SomeProperty == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("myComplexObject.SomeProperty");
```

The caller will instantly know what's wrong.

Note that I don't use the nameof-operator, because that again would just give me `SomeProperty` instead of `myComplexObject.SomeProperty`. I could do `nameof(myComplexObject) + "." + nameof(myComplexObject.SomeProperty`, but I need to give that some more thought, doesn't look right on the first glance.

And here are my reasons why I think the other approaches are worse than mine:

Some said I should validate in the model, which I won't do because the model does not know how the object has to be validated for methods it doesn't know. If it's the overall object instance validity, sure, stick it in the model or if you ask me even a business layer for business validations, but this is not that situation.

Others said I could just use the null-coalescing operator (`?.` in C#), which I also won't do, because it's not a "if null then just work with that" scenario, but a "I will not do a thing if this is null, and you should feel bad for giving me null, fix your code" scenario.

Then there are code contracts, which provide a sweet way of validating arguments and have some more really nice benefits, but ultimately the same question arises: how can I tell the caller which value exactly of a complex object is invalid? He needs to know that property X of argument Y is wrong, nothing less. Although code contracts aren't the answer to my question, I think my answer can be used there as well, if the same situation occurs.

And then there was a suggestion that I should not validate the properties of objects in that place, but in the function where it's needed. The thing is, the property is barely used to be passed as a single separated value to another function. Plus it would kind of battle the idea of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all my models have a Validate method, this way I just call it and if it returns false (which means I got errors) I call another method to get the errors from it and display to the user, something like this:

```
if (person == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (person));

// Validates only 1 property.
if (!person.Validate (nameof (person.MyProperty)))
    DisplayErrors (person);

// Validates all properties.
if (!person.Validate ())
    DisplayErrors (person);
```

The reason behind it is that in most cases I have to allow the model to be invalid while the user is filling the information. I use these method with the interface INotifyDataErrorInfo for WPF to enable the UI to refresh when errors occur.

When only part of object is required for a method or operation, a facade model is the solution where you create a new class that envelopes your more complex one, and the facade class have the Validate method too to do partial validation.

Comment: The idea was that specific methods need only specific properties of the object. This one needs the name, while another one might need the age. Validating only the necessary property is supposed to help validate the object for only this method. If this method doesn't require the other properties, why should it validate them? That was my thought process. I barely have any unexpected `NullReferenceException`s this way. Have I taken a wrong turn there?

Comment: If your model is used in different scenarios where some of its properties are not required and in other scenarios it is, then your model is wrong, you need two different classes. If you don't do this you'll have a maintenance hell, because your data must be valid according to your model without needing to know at which context it is going to be being used. Not only that, that method is inside the model's class so you can cache validations to prevent unnecessary re-validation when the object is not changed, so performance is never an issue, remember.

Comment: Updated my answer with the optional property name parameter to the validate method, I have that option but rarely use it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your first sentence tells me that for example when I pass a person to a function which queries a database to find other persons with the same last name, all the other properties of the person also have to be valid, even though they're not used in the function. Is this what you're saying? I think when I don't do the validation in those methods but in the model itself it makes more sense, since then I don't validate anything from the person in the method at all. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Each model class would have a Validate method that can either validate the entire model or just one of its properties. The idea is that the model knows how to validate itself, all the requirements to have a valid name, valid age etc are in the model. Another thing, If your method only needs the last name then you should only ask the last name, not the entire person, it makes it more clear to other programmers because they don't have to read the method's body to see why the person was asked.

Comment: If you still want a simpler version of person object, I would use is the Facade pattern, it would still have the validate methods but expose only the properties needed, you could have a model class named SearchPersonCriteria or something like that as it would make it clear that you are using the person to search other people.

Comment: I'm starting to think that my example wasn't the best one. The scenario is not limited to model classes, it also applies to context objects or layers or anything you can think of. A context class may have properties for certain services, and it doesn't know by itself whether it's in a valid state or not, because that depends on the caller.

Comment: That's why I put validation in the models, I normally have context classes that are used to save to the database, it doesn't know if the model is ok to be saved so it asks the model to validate itself. Now, if your context class have properties itself that needs to be validated, then your Context class should know how to validate it, in that case, just create private methods to do it and throw exceptions if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [code contracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts).  Certainly, checking as you have shown is a perfectly fine way to validate parameters ... assuming that you are only validating the fields that you are using.  Validating fields that you don't reference is asking for trouble (unless that is the explicit purpose of the method).

The newest version of C# provides a '?.' operator which lets you do things like this:

```
int? length = customers?.Length;
```

or

```
string name = person?.Name;
```

This allows you to protect yourself from null reference exceptions and may in some cases be preferable to pre-validation.

Oh, and running the code analysis tool generally flags using parameters before they are validated, so at least that tools considers it a best practice.

**Update** (in response to comment):
It largely depends on what you are trying to do.  If you are creating an API and want to return the best error message possible, then what you have suggested it probably about the best you can do.  This assumes you are mainly concerned with communicating with your API's consumer.

If your main interest is insuring that the data provided to your method is valid and will not cause your method to behavior poorly (CYA) you should look into contracts.  Contracts have the advantage of providing post conditions (assuring your method didn't return something unexpected) and invariant conditions (assuring to haven't changes something you didn't intend to).    Contracts can provide both static (compile time) assurances as well as runtime assurances.  There is a fairly fine grained way to manage contract options.  Runtime contract violations generate contract exceptions which people may be less familiar with.  Compile time complaints may also not be familiar to users. 
This assumes you are mainly concerned with assuring proper operation or not getting blamed for misuse of your API.

You can use both, for example using Contracts for compile time checks and simpler 'if' checks for runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of all those things. When a method is supposed to be able to handle nulls, then yes, I do consider the Elvis operator "?.". Since my goal is to have very clear exceptions, I'm not sure if code contracts are what I want. If a required property of a passed complex type is null, I want the caller to know exactly which value is broken. I haven't used code contracts yet, but when I did a very quick research yesterday, I didn't see this behavior. But I'm willing to be tought otherwise. :)

Comment: In response to your update: your first paragraph pretty much hits it. In public methods I'm always concerned about what it's working with. I've learned that not trusting anything prevents me from failures based on unchecked assumptions. You know what they say about assuming, so I avoid it whenever possible. And it really helps. I barely get any unexpected NullReferenceExceptions thanks to that. Whenever I have to fix someones code, that's the first I look for, and it has proven to be overly successful. Private methods are in a closed environment, so I don't need this kind of validation there.

Answer (score 0):

To me, sounds like a design issue for 99% of the cases. Is a person valid without a name? I suspect not. And if not, why do you allow one to be created without one? And if you (for some reason) do allow it, isn't it the responsibility of the object to maintain it's own "valid-ness"? I would lean on something like data annotations to markup with metadata the required states, and simply check that the passed in person is "valid"

Comment: It's less about validating the integrity of the object as a whole, more about validating whether the passed arguments are in a valid state for the working method. An object might be perfectly valid when a certain property is null, but a method might require this property to be set.